# Draw the Hilbert Curve

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity, graphical-output, fractal

A Hilbert Curve is a type of space-filling curve, and it basically maps a line to a plane. Each point in the line corresponds to just one point in the plane, and each point in the plane corresponds to just one point on the line. Shown are iterations 0 through 4 of the Hilbert Curve:

Iterations 0 up to 4:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

The objective of this task: Write code that draws the fourth iteration of the Hilbert Curve, as defined above. Your code should be complete - in other words, if you create a function to draw the Hilbert Curve, your code must call that function. The output can either be displayed directly on the screen, or you can write the output to an image file. The curve may be rotated or flipped, but lines must intersect at right angles and the output cannot be stretched. ASCII art is appreciated but will not be accepted. Shortest code in bytes wins!

Comment: Is the number of times an input? Or can we choose any value at least 4?

Comment: Is ASCII art considered graphical?

Comment: No; sorry - then it'd be a duplicate of another question

Comment: @JorgePerez Can the curve have a different orientation? Like a vertically flipped or 90-deg rotate version of your examples

Comment: Yes! Although the overall shape must still be square

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>39</s> 38 bytes

```
O5:"tZjJ*JQ-wJq+t2+&y2j+_v2/]XG25Y01ZG
```

This takes the number of iterations as input. If you want to hard-code it, replace `i` by the number.

The program is a port of the Matlab code by Jonas Lundgren shown [here](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2012/01/25/generating-hilbert-curves/).

The result is shown below. You can also try it at [MATL Online!](https://matl.io/?code=O5%3A%22tZjJ%2aJQ-wJq%2Bt2%2B%26y2j%2B_v2%2F%5DXG25Y01ZG&inputs=&version=19.4.0) It takes a couple of seconds to produce the output. This compiler is experimental; you may need to refresh the page and press "Run" again if it doesn't initially work.

[image]

#### Explanation

```
O          % Push 0. This is the initial value of "z" in the original code
5:"        % Do 5 times
  t        %   Duplicate
  Zj       %   Complex conjugate
  J*       %   Multiply by 1j (imaginary unit). This is "w" in the original code
  JQ-      %   Subtract 1+1j
  w        %   Swap: brings copy of "z" to top
  Jq+      %   Add 1-1j
  t        %   Duplicate
  2+       %   Add 2
  &y       %   Duplicate the third element from top
  2j+_     %   Add 2j and negate
  v        %   Concatenate the three matrices vertically
  2/       %   Divide by 2
]          % End
XG         % Plot (in complex plane). The numbers are joined by straight lines
25Y0       % Push string 'square'
1ZG        % Make axis square
```

Comment: Could you explain how your code works?

Comment: The algorithm is exactly as in the link. But I will add an explanation

Comment: @Jorge Explanation added

Comment: omg, the one you based yours of is so much easier than mine =/

Comment: @flawr All credit to Jonas Lundgren :-)

Comment: @LuisMendo I used his approach now for the [sierpinsky arrowhead](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/100363/24877) perhaps you can still use that one again to port it to MATL :)

Answer (score 7):

## MATLAB, <s>264</s> <s>262</s> 161 bytes

This works still very much the same, except that we basically calculate the "derivative" of the hilbert curve, that we then "integrate" via `cumsum`. This reduces the code size by quite a bunch of bytes.

```
function c;plot(cumsum([0,h(1,1+i,4)]));axis equal;end function v=h(f,d,l);v=d*[i*f,1,-i*f];if l;l=l-1;D=i*d*f;w=h(f,d,l);x=h(-f,D,l);v=[x,D,w,d,w,-D,-x];end;end
```

#### Old version

This is just a plain recursive approach. I used complex numbers to store vectorial information for simplicity. You can change the curve at the part `h(0,1,1+i,4)`. The first argument `p=0` is the initial position, the second argument `f` is a flag for the orientation (`+1` or `-1`), the third argument `d` is the direction/rotation in which the curve should be drawn and the fourth one `l` is the recursion depth.

```
function c;hold on;h(0,1,1+i,4);axis equal;end function p=h(p,f,d,l);q=@plot;if l;l=l-1;d=i*d*f;p=h(p,-f,d,l);q(p+[0,d]);p=p+d;d=-i*d*f;p=h(p,f,d,l);q(p+[0,d]);p=p+d;p=h(p,f,d,l);d=-i*d*f;q(p+[0,d]);p=p+d;p=h(p,-f,d,l);else;q(p + d*[0,i*f,1+i*f,1]);p=p+d;end;end
```

This is what it looks like in older versions:

[image]

This is what it looks like in 2015b:

[image]

-->

Comment: In Matlab R2015b it [plots in colors](https://s17.postimg.org/jyqh4m6nj/untitled.png) <3

Comment: Haha so cool :)

Comment: @LuisMendo I was now able to golf it a bit with the `cumsum` idea which is just brilliant!

Comment: Starting from Matlab 2016b you can define functions in scripts. This can save you a few more bytes so you're down to [144](https://tio.run/##NYo7DsMgGIP3nIIR0h@pSN0QW24RZUA8FCQIaXgkt6dEbQfL/mxHlWU1TfmYDJLec6S8kcdtig82HkFmlNZ4ZI5@pGLYpcq82bKp7OKGqlixBQ2e8Cr0OLvRAgPabQFnkYdJuFH38vwfKSNwdaAWpi9VMV89n309gU5ArwXMpm8Nu48ZqxJSCXh@wooZsIeDF1kIGeTlEjLvIn1rHw). (Note that to make this work on TIO I had to move the definition of `h` to the first line. In Matlab this would have to be the last line of the script).

Answer (score 7):

### R, 90 bytes

```
n=scan();a=1+1i;b=1-1i;z=0;for(k in 1:n)z=c((w<-1i*Conj(z))-a,z-b,z+a,b-w)/2;plot(z,t="s")
```

Shameless R-port of the the algorithm used in the link posted by @Luis Mendo.

For `n=5` we get:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>266</s> ... <s>233</s> 232 bytes

A SVG rendering of the Hilbert Curve.

```js
document.write('<svg><path fill=none stroke=red d="M8 8'+(f=(i,s='2',d=x=y=8)=>i?f(i-1,s.replace(/./g,c=>[32410401423,,10432423401][+c]||c)):s.replace(/./g,c=>c-4?(d+=c&1&&c-2,''):`L${x+=4-'4840'[d&=3]} ${y+=4-'0484'[d]}`))(5)+'">')
```

*Saved 1 byte thanks to Neil*

Comment: Try `fill=none`

Answer (score 3):

## MATLAB/Octave, 202 bytes

I noticed the [version @LuisMendo linked](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2012/01/25/generating-hilbert-curves/) <s>is</s> was way shorter than previous ["handmade" solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/100356/24877) but uses an entirely different approach. I'm posting a golfed version here now as a CW:

This version is based on the Lindenmayer system approach:

```
A=zeros(0,2);B=A;C=A;D=A;n=[0,1];e=[1,0];for k=1:4;a=[B;n;A;e;A;-n;C];b=[A;e;B;n;B;-e;D];c=[D;-e;C;-n;C;e;A];D=[C;-n;D;-e;D;n;B];A=a;B=b;C=c;end;A=[0,0;cumsum(A)];plot(A(:,1),A(:,2));axis off;axis equal
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

## Python 3, <s>177</s> <s>175</s> 171 bytes

A simple implementation of the Lindenmayer system for the Hilbert curve. Golfing suggestions welcome!

**Edit:** -2 bytes thanks to Kade. -3 bytes from restructuring how the Hilbert curve is built. -1 byte with thanks to ETHproductions.

```python
from turtle import*;s="a";exec('t=""\nfor c in s:t+=c>"F"and"+-abFF-+baFFba-+FFab+-"[c<"b"::2]or c\ns=t;'*5)
for c in s:
 if"-">c:rt(90)
 elif"F">c:lt(90)
 elif"a">c:fd(9)
```

[image]

**Ungolfing**

```python
import turtle

hilbert_seq = "a"

for _ in range(5):
    new_seq = ""
    for char in hilbert_seq:
        if char == "a":
            new_seq += "-bF+aFa+Fb-"
        elif char == "b":
            new_seq += "+aF-bFb-Fa+"
        else:
            new_seq += char
    hilbert_seq = new_seq

for char in hilbert_seq:
    if char == "F":
        turtle.forward(9)
    elif char == "+":
        turtle.right(90)
    elif char == "-":
        turtle.left(90)
```

Comment: Changing how you form `t` can save two bytes: `t+=[[c,"+AF-BFB-FA+"][c=="B"],"-BF+AFA+FB-"][c=="A"]`. Since the pattern is almost the same for the two of them I wonder if there's some way to use that..

Comment: Perhaps change `if c>"E":` to `if"E"<c:` to save a byte?

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica (Wolfram Language) 76 bytes

After Mathematica 11.1, there is a [HilbertCurve](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HilbertCurve.html) function, but i don't want to use it

```
Region@Line@ReIm@Nest[Join[w=I Conjugate@#-1-I,t=#+I-1,t+2,-2I-w]/2&,{0},#]&
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## MSWLogo (Version 6.5b), 136 bytes

Based on the final Hilbert curve program [here](http://eurologo.web.elte.hu/lectures/batagel1.htm).

```
to h :n :a :l
if :n=0[stop]
rt :a
h :n-1(-:a):l
fd :l
lt :a
h :n-1 :a :l
fd :l
h :n-1 :a :l
lt :a
fd :l
h :n-1(-:a):l
rt :a
end
h 5 90 9
```

A function `h` is defined, which takes number of iterations `:n` (1-based), angle `:a`, length `:l`. It is recursive, calling a lower iteration of itself with the angle `:a` negated in two instances to get the orientation correct.

- `rt :a`, `lt :a` rotate the turtle (triangle thingy whose path is traced) right, left by `:a` degrees.
- `fd :l` moves the turtle forward by `:l` steps.

Finally, the function is called: `h 5 90 9`. The turtle can be hidden for an extra 2 bytes, `ht`.

[image: (5-1)-th iteration]

Comment: What's happening on the top left corner?

Comment: @flawr That's the turtle. It can be hidden by appending `ht`.

Answer (score 1):

### Mathematica 128 Bytes

```
Graphics[Line@AnglePath[Total/@Split[Cases[Nest[#/.{-2->(s=##&@@#&)[l={-1,2,0,1,-2,0,-2,1,0,2,-1}],2->s@-l}&,{-2},4],-1|1|0],#!=0&][[;;-2,;;-2]]*Pi/2]]
```

Replace the 4 above with a different number of iterations if you like.

Done as a Lindenmayer system with integer sequences rather than string sequences so the second production rule is just the negative of the first rule. This version is 151 bytes.

The port of Jonas Lundgren's MATLAB code is only 128 bytes.

```
z=0;Graphics[Line[{Re[#],Im[#]}&/@Flatten[Table[w=I*Conjugate[z];z={w-(a=1+I),z-(b=1-I),z+a,b-w}/2,{k,5}][[5]]]],AspectRatio->1]
```

I see that in a future version of Mathematica, this may become really short, something like:

```
Graphics@HilbertCurve[n]
```

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HilbertCurve.html

Answer (score 1):

## [LindenMASM](https://github.com/kade-robertson/pylasma), 63 Bytes

Another question with a LindenMASM answer? Awesome!

```
STT
AXI A
INC 5
SET F 0
RPL A -BF+AFA+FB-
RPL B +AF-BFB-FA+
END
```

Once again, due to some drawing bugs with Python's `turtle`, sometimes when you run this the whole drawing isn't there. However you can see it does actually work:

[image: 4th iteration]