# Draw the Sierpinski Arrowhead Curve

Tags: code-golf, math, ascii-art, graphical-output

### Introduction

The [Sierpinski Arrowhead Curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpi%C5%84ski_arrowhead_curve) is a curve that's limit is Sierpinski's Triangle.

It first starts like this:

```
 _
/ \
```

Then, each line is replaced with a rotated version of the first one:

```
  _
 / \
 \ /
_/ \_
```

Next:

```
     _
    / \
    \ /
   _/ \_
  /     \
  \_   _/
 _  \ /  _
/ \_/ \_/ \
```

[image: Sierpinski Arrowhead Curve Evolution]

### Your task

Given a number *n*, output the *n*-th iteration of the Sierpinski Arrowhead Curve.

You may choose 0 or 1-indexed input, but please specify that in your answer.

You may generate an image, or use Ascii Art in the format I have given above.

You may not use built-ins to generate this curve.

Remember, this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the code with the fewest bytes wins.

Answer (score 14):

## Octave, <s>240 236</s> 221 bytes

This is made with the same idea [used here](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2012/01/25/generating-hilbert-curves/) but I had to change it to fit the sierpinsky arrowhead curve.

```
m=input(0);g=2*pi/6;u=cos(g);v=sin(g);A=[1,0];B=[u,v];C=[-u,v];D=-A;E=-B;F=-C;for k=1:m;f=[E;F;A];b=[A;B;C];A=[B;A;F];d=[C;D;E];C=[D;C;B];E=[F;E;D];B=b;D=d;F=f;end;A=[0,0;cumsum(A)];plot(A(:,1),A(:,2));axis off;axis equal
```

[image]

Comment: `u=.5;v=3^u/2;B=[u,v];C=[-u,v];A=C<0;` is 16 bytes shorter :) You can also do `axis off equal` to save another 5 bytes.

Answer (score 3):

## Haskell + diagrams, 176 bytes

```
import Diagrams.Prelude
import Diagrams.Backend.SVG
g n=renderSVG"a"(mkWidth 99).strokeT.a n
a 0=hrule 1
a n|b<-a(n-1)=b%6<>b<>b%(-6);a%n=rotateBy(1/n).reflectY$a::Trail V2 Double
```

Makes a svg file with transparent background called "a".

`g 0` outputs a horizontal line, `g 1` is `/¯\`.

[image]

Comment: Great, I didn't know about `Diagrams`!

Comment: @flawr, it's great but the usual Haskell graphical program caveats apply. It would be great to just call the equivalent of of `plot() ` to open a window.

Answer (score 2):

## MSWLogo (Version 6.5b), 102 bytes

Takes the two functions `shapeL`, `shapeR` given [here](http://infohost.nmt.edu/~blewis/html/sierpinskiarrowhead-student.html) and merges them by adding an extra argument `:a`, which calls the opposite function when negated.

```
to s :n :a :l
if :n=0[fd :l stop]
rt :a
s :n-1(-:a):l
lt :a
s :n-1 :a :l
lt :a
s :n-1(-:a):l
rt :a
end
```

A function `s` is defined, which takes number of iterations `:n` (1-based), angle `:a`, length `:l`. It is recursive, calling a lower iteration of itself with the angle `:a` negated in two instances to get the orientation correct.

- `rt :a`, `lt :a` rotate the turtle (triangle thingy whose path is traced) right, left by `:a` degrees.
- `fd :l` moves the turtle forward by `:l` steps.

The function is to be called with `:a` equal to 60.

[image: Arrowheads]

Here, `repeat` is essentially a FOR loop, with built-in counter `repcount`. `pu` and `pd` mean "pen up" and "pen down", which stop the turtle from drawing while its position is being set using `setxy`.

The drawings of each iteration have been called with length `:l` equal to `power 2 (7-repcount)`, which decreases exponentially; this is because the definition uses the same `:l` in the recursive step, so with fixed `:l` the overall size of the output will increase exponentially with `:n`.

Comment: This is the right language for the job, but technically answers aren't allowed extra data, so ideally you would encode the 60 in your answer.

Comment: @Neil So I just include `60` in the byte count?

Comment: I'm not sure that it's that simple, but I don't know the language myself.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, 124 bytes

Based off of the code in the Wikipedia article.

```
from turtle import*
def c(o,a):
 if o:o-=1;c(o,-a);lt(a);c(o,a);lt(a);c(o,-a)
 else:fd(9)
n=input()
if n%2==0:lt(60)
c(n,60)
```

Order 0 is a straight line.

Comment: You have to change your code to use an angle of 60 degrees, otherwise it will not approximate the Sierpinsky triangle. Also, the orientation changes depending on the order, which I don't think is correct. https://trinket.io/python/a803546939

Comment: The logo answer also gives a function that takes the angle as a parameter, so I think that it is OK. As far as the orientation goes, it is still the same curve, just rotated.

Comment: The logo answer is always the same rotation, though. Yours is a different rotation for each order, and they are not all the same. This is not okay. Look at the pictures the question contains.

Comment: Where does the challenge say that the rotations have to be the same?

Comment: The rules say this: Given a number n, output the n-th iteration of the Sierpinski Arrowhead Curve. ✓ You may choose to 0- or 1-index, but please specify in your answer. ✓ You may generate an image, or use Ascii Art in the format I have above. ✓ (I'm generating an image). You may not use built-ins to generate this curve. ✓ My entry breaks none of the rules, so it is valid.

Comment: Also, if you say that the graphics output has to be the same as the pictures in the challenge, then the logo entry is disqualified too. It doesn't have the same rotation as the pictures.

Comment: It says "[the] limit is Sierpinski's Triangle". Your output doesn't follow that.

Comment: Yes, it does. The triangle is just upside down for even n. That is just as valid as having it be sideways.

Comment: Any math major can tell you that a limit must converge. Yours does not.

Comment: I'm temporarily removing this post in compliance with our [policy about answers not meeting the challenge specification](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/7990/12012). Please feel free to edit your answer and to flag it for moderator attention so it can be undeleted.

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica / Wolfram Language 73 bytes

```
s=1;Region@Line@AnglePath[Nest[Join@@({#,s=-s,s}&/@#)&,{#~Mod~2},#]Pi/3]&
```

Simple explanation：
[AnglePath](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AnglePath.html)[{θ1,θ2,θ3,…}] gives the list of 2D coordinates corresponding to a path that starts at {0,0}, then takes a series of steps of unit length at successive relative angles θi.

n=1

```
Graphics@Line@AnglePath[60°{1,-1,-1}]
```

n=2

```
Graphics@Line@AnglePath[60°{0,1,1, -1,-1,-1, -1,1,1}]
```

n=3

```
Graphics@Line@AnglePath[60°{1,-1,-1, 1,1,1, 1,-1,-1, -1,1,1, -1,-1,-1, -1,1,1, -1,-1,-1, 1,1,1, 1,-1,-1}]
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 62 bytes

```
Graphics@Line@AnglePath[Pi/3Nest[Flatten@{-#,1,#,1,-#}&,0,#]]&
```

Comment: How does that work?

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript (ES6), 180 bytes

```js
f=(n,d=0,r=n=>` `.repeat(n))=>n?f(--n,d=3-d%3).map(s=>r([l=s.length/2,0,1,~n&1][d]+l)+s+r([,1,0,~n&1][d]+l)).concat(f(n,d+1).map(s=>s+r(!(d%3))+a.shift(),a=f(n,d+2))):[`_/\\`[d%3]]
```

```html
<input type=number min=1 oninput=o.textContent=f(this.value).join`\n`><pre id=o>
```

Returns an array of strings. Getting the spacing right was the hardest part! Pure string version for 205 bytes:

```
f=(n,d=0,r=n=>` `.repeat(n))=>n?f(--n,d=3-d%3).replace(/.+/g,s=>r([l=s.length/2,0,1,~n&1][d]+l)+s+r([,1,0,~n&1][d]+l))+`\n`+f(n,d+1).replace(/.+/g,s=>s+r(!(d%3))+a.shift(),a=f(n,d+2).split`\n`):`_/\\`[d%3]
```